# 1px vertical gap on right of images in simple html signature

Tags: html, css, email, space, signature

I have tried EVERYTHING I could find.  The famous 1px vertical gap on the right side of images still doesn't seem to have a solid fix!  Please someone help to to resolve this.  I literally have no hair left after pulling them out one by one!

Plesae can someone help?

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ RESET STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
    body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    img{
        border:0 none;
        height:auto;
        line-height:100%;
        outline:none;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    a img{
        border:0 none;
    }

    .imageFix{
        display:block;
    }

    table, tr, td{
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }

    #bodyTable{
        height:100% !important;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:799px !important;
        max-width: 799px !important;
    }
</style>
<table bgcolor="red" width="799" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="176" height="115">
            <img src="https://www.htref.co.za/signatures/images/img01-01.png" class="imageFix" alt="logo" width="176" height="115">
        </td>
        <td width="623" height="115">
            <img src="https://www.htref.co.za/signatures/images/img01.png" class="imageFix" alt="logo" width="623" height="115">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Example show of 1px vertical gap on the right side of the image

[image: Example show of 1px vertical gap on the right side of the image]

Comment: Your code seems normal in my browser. Are you viewing your site at 100% zoom? Also, what browser/screen are you using?

Comment: It’s an email signature. It’s not meant to be viewed in a browser.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. How about using a solid background the same as the image has?

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, no border appear !

Put a lightgrey background-color to body, anything at the right of the image.

Why using a table when you can do this with Flexbox, for example ?

Comment: Because this isn’t a website. It’s an email signature. The images need to be snug against each other as the images are sliced

Answer (score 0):

```
bgcolor="red"
```

Is it necessary? Without this the gap disappeared.

Comment: The red background is there to simply show the gaps. If I remove the red, there will still be a gap. Changing the background color doesn’t solve the gap. The point of this thread is to solve the gap.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not put any white space before or after your images? I kind of remember that whitespace in your source code HTML is collapsed but still rendered as a space character in the output. So no space, tab or newline character before or after your `img` tag.

But if this is all you signature has, you don't need a `table` (which is a very 90s way to align pictures). You could use directly your `img`s (but still without  whitespace before or after your tags):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body{
        width: 799px
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body><img src="https://www.htref.co.za/signatures/images/img01-01.png" 
         alt="logo" width="176" height="115" 
     /><img src="https://www.htref.co.za/signatures/images/img01.png" 
         alt="logo" width="623" height="115" 
    /></body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Ferrrmolina: The edit you made cancelled what I was trying to show. Read my comment please!